# How to properly rewrite a post tag?

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

Suppose I have a post tag which have as term id `480`, I'm trying to create a redirect using `add_rewrite_rule`, so far I did:

```
function term_custom_redirect()
{
    $referer_url = "en/tag/a-lange-sohne";
    add_rewrite_rule(
        "^$referer_url/?$",
        'index.php?p=' . 480,
        "top"
    );

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'term_custom_redirect', 10, 0);
```

the code should add a rewrite for the term id `480`, so when the user visit the following url: `example.com/en/tag/a-lange-sohne/`, the tag page associated to `480` should be loaded, but I get a 404, even though I added `flush_rewrite_rules` at the end (I also saved the permalink from the backend).

***UPDATE:***

The main issue here is that some post tag contains within the url `-en`, and I want remove it, eg:

```
example.com/en/tag/a-lange-sohne-en/
```

should become:

```
example.com/en/tag/a-lange-sohne/
```

the taxonomy is `post_tag` and is the default available in wordpress, so I doesn't have created any new taxonomy:

[image]

I though that my initial solution would work, but for some reason doesn't. I also tried a new hook that should handle the job:

```
function update_term_link($permalink, $tag)
{
    if (strpos($permalink, '-en') !== false) {
        $permalink = str_replace('-en', '', $permalink);
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter('tag_link', 'update_term_link', 10, 2);
```

but it doesn't work either (I've refreshed the permalink always).

NB: using the `tag_link` hook I can see the new permalink structure correctly, it is simply not accessible with 404 error.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but technically as written you have two trailing forward slashes, with only the second one being optional

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the tips, I tried to remove the slash but same issue, the `$referer_url` have: `en/tag/a-lange-sohne`

Comment: Also, once again possibly not related to your problem, but since you aren't using capturing parentheses, `name` will be empty because `$matches[1]` isn't associated with anything.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I have updated the code, thanks

Comment: Lastly, instead of `p=489`, can you try `page_id=480`

Comment: @ChrisHaas I tried and same issue, I also tried with `tag_id`

Comment: What is 480? Is it a taxonomy term, or a post/page/cpt?

Comment: From what you've said, it looks like you need to use `'index.php?post_tag=' . 480` instead of `'index.php?p=' . 480`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's a `post_tag` taxonomy, and @cabrerahector I tried `index.php?post_tag=480'` but still 404 maybe I did something incorrect?

Comment: Did you re-save your permalinks after making that change? (WP Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks).

Comment: @cabrerahector yes, I also added this `flush_rewrite_rules();` after the `add_rewrite_rule`

Comment: Just to be clear, you've created a custom taxonomy via `register_taxonomy`, and the taxonomy key is `post_tag`? And then you have a term who's name/title is `480`, and `480` is **not** the ID of the term. Is this correct?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I've added more details to my question, please check the update, thanks

Comment: How is the `/en/` coming in? Do you have WPML installed, or some sort of translation plugin? Or is this a subfolder install?

Comment: Backing up a step, do you want the world including all search engines to know that the URL `/en/tag/a-lange-sohne-en/` exists? Or do you want to say, "oops, that shouldn't exist, please go to `/en/tag/a-lange-sohne/` instead. If that's the case, you really want a 301 redirect, and you probably also want to fix the term in the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```php
function term_custom_redirect()
{
    $referer_url = "en/tag/a-lange-sohne";
    $tag_id = 480;
    $tag = get_term($tag_id, 'post_tag');

    if ( $tag ) {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            "^{$referer_url}/?$",
            'index.php?tag=' . $tag->slug,
            "top"
        );

        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }
}
add_action('init', 'term_custom_redirect', 10, 0);
```

Here we're using the `tag` parameter to ask WordPress to find the tag archive page by slug.

The function uses [get_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term/) to get the tag by ID (in your case, the ID is `480`) and then we can use that information to retrieve the tag object, including its slug. This is good because if the tag gets renamed it doesn't affect our code as the ID will remain the same.

[image: Screenshot of rewrite rule in effect]

Comment: Also, consider removing the `flush_rewrite_rules();` line from your function, it should only be used sparingly as it's an expensive call (in terms of performance). Saving permalinks manually (Settings > Permalinks) achieves the same effect.

Comment: thanks for your solution, is this working on your end? 'cause my wordpress installation keep returning 404, I don't know at this point what could be the cause, also thanks for the `flush_rewrite_rules` tip. I did a `var_dump` of `var_dump([
'url' => $referer_url,
'slug' => $term->slug
]);
 die;`
and this is the content: `array(2) { ["url"]=> string(22) "/en/tag/a-lange-sohne/" ["slug"]=> string(16) "a-lange-sohne-en" }`

Comment: Yep, it is working on my local dev environment. I tested it before sharing the code here :P Added screenshot to the answer.

Comment: thanks for your solution, I've accepted your answer even though in my case the solution was a little bit different, I wrote an answer to explain what has worked for me, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer provided by [@cabrerahector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9131961/cabrerahector) I was able to fix the problem, but in my case I have to remove the `en` part from `$referer_url`, so the final code looks like:

```
$referer_url = str_replace('/en/', '', $referer_url);

add_rewrite_rule(
    "^$referer_url?$",
    'index.php?tag=' . $term->slug,
    "top"
);
```